# Understanding "ihm" in "so fiel ihm das Herz doch eine Elle tiefer herab"

Tags: sentence-structure, dative

The question is on the highlighted clause in this excerpt from [Die beiden Wanderer](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_beiden_Wanderer_%281857%29) as collected by the Grimm brothers.

> Zwei Tage gieng das so fort, aber als am dritten Tag der Wald kein Ende nehmen wollte, und der Schneider sein Brot aufgegessen hatte, **so fiel ihm das Herz doch eine Elle tiefer herab**: indessen verlor er nicht den Muth, sondern verließ sich auf Gott und auf sein Glück.

**Question**

1. Am I OK to think:  *ihm* is telling me whose heart is in question, i.e. that it is the tailor's heart, and can be assimilated to the dative in expressions like *jemandem die Haare kämmen* (in which *jemandem* tells me whose hair is in question).
2. Am I OK to think:  If the context is right, the same clause *so fiel ihm das Herz* could be about someone's heart falling to another.  For example, if [Snow White](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Sneewittchen_%281857%29) came to the end proposed for her by the queen and the poor heart fell to some beast, *so fiel ihm das Herz* could mean *so fiel dem tier das Herz des Mädchens.*  The same thing holds for *jemandem die Haare kämmen*.  For example, if we are talking about barbers, *jemandem* may be a barber and the hair belong to a patron.
3. Assuming I am OK so far, is *so fiel ihm das Herz* as standard (Hochdeutsch) as *jemandem die Haare kämmen* or is it more regional?
4. On the same assumption, is *so fiel ihm das Herz* as ordinary as *jemandem die Haare kämmen*?

**Background**

For example of the usage of dative in a genitive sense that is said to be regional, see [this earlier post](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/30591/7629)--in which *Das ist dem Bauer sein Pferd* is said to be southern and not Hochdeutsch.  (As noted there, it's got a feature not present in the other cases because *sein* and *dem Bauer* duplicate the same idea.)

Basically I am imagining three cases.  (a) The form of *so fiel ihm das Herz* is as standard and ordinary as *jemandem die Haare kämmen*.  You can use the form today without sounding odd.  (b) The form is standard but not ordinary.  It sounds bookish.  (c) It is not standard and not ordinary.  For example, it was a regionalism even in 1857.

Obviously I don't mean any value judgment when I say Hochdeutsch is standard.

I am happy to get answers in English or German.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is standard contemporary usage of the dative, no regional variety, not aging (If you disregard the "Elle" which is an ancient unit - See below for a contemporary expression). And no, it has nothing to do with the "Ersatzdativ".

Dative is used here to point out it happens **to him**, and **one of his parts** is affected.

This form is called *Dativus possesivus*  and no, it is not the same form as "jemandem das Auto waschen" (which uses dative to express someone having an advantage from something), but rather like "Ihm schmerzen die Füsse" which somehow expresses it is *his own feet* that cause pain *to him*.

This is one of the usages of dative that is not present in English and needs to be expressed with pronouns there.

> Das Herz fiel ihm in die Hose

Is an idiom commonly used to express "he was shocked".

Note *dativus possesivus* can be used to parts that definitely belong to a *person* like:

> Der Friseur schneidet dem Mann die Haare

But not with things like

> Er putzt dem Auto die Scheinwerfer

Comment: On *jemandem das Auto waschen* being of advantage but not possession. (x) Can you use the expression when the car does not belong to *jemandem*. For example, the car belongs to A, B was supposed to wash it, but C does it (so B can study for the exam). Can you say *C wascht B (dative) das Auto*? (y) If * jemandem die Haare kämmen* is also of advantage, then the same question.  For example, suppose I take my little daughter into a hair shop and have her combed.  Can this be a case of *mir die Haare kämmen*?

Comment: If no to (x) and (y), then I would find it difficult to see a real distinction between cases of advantage vs. possession.

Comment: Is *Ersatzdativ* the grammatical term for cases like *jemandem das Auto waschen* and *jemandem die Haare kämmen*? If not, what are those cases called? Thanks.

Comment: With *jemandem die Haare kämmen* you've hit a corner case - I can't decide whether it's *advantage* or *possession* - maybe both (note: *possession* only works for body parts - like hair and heart). You might have seen I deliberately changed to another example ;) . "Ich putze dir die Fenster" works both if it's your windows or *your task* to clean the windows - clearly *advantage*

Comment: @Catomic *Ersatzdativ* is *replacing a genitive with a dative* in some German dialects that was referred to in your question (Dem Bauer sein Pferd). In hochdeutsch, it is **wrong**.

Answer (score 1):

Du hast schon eine sehr gute Antwort erhalten, aber ich möchte auf mehr Punkte eingehen.

1. Ja, die Konstruktion ist ähnlich zu „jemandem die Haare schneiden“. Ein vielleicht noch einfacheres Beispiel ist

   > Ich wasche mir die Hände. (I am washing my hands.)

   was im Deutschen die gebräuchliche Form ist. Wenn ich stattdessen „ich wasche meine Hände“ sage, ist das nicht falsch, wirkt aber so, als wäre da eine Distanz zwischen mir und meinen Händen.

   Genau so und dichter an unserem Beispiel ist

   > Ihm sank das Herz.

   die deutsche Entsprechung zu

   > His heart sank.
2. Meinem Empfinden nach ist die Konstruktion nicht „ihm fiel das Herz“, sondern „ihm fiel das Herz herab“. Dein Beispiel ergibt im deutschen keinen rechten Sinn, aber wir können uns vorstellen, dass der Jäger, der der Königin das Herz bringen soll, stolpert und es fallen lässt:

   > Dem Jäger fiel das Herz des Wildschweins herunter.
3. Die Konstruktion an sich ist völlig normal. Ein anderes Beispiel mit Körperteilen ist

   > Mir fallen die Augen zu.
4. „Ihm fiel das Herz eine Elle tiefer herab“ ist ein Bild dafür, dass seine Stimmung schlechter wird. „Er schneidet ihm die Haare“ ist eine direkte Beschreibung für eine gewöhnliche Handlung. Daher ist letzteres häufiger. (Und heute würde das Herz eher einen Meter als eine Elle fallen.)

Answer (score 0):

Ja, der Dativ ist da völlig in Ordnung. 
Fragestellung beim Dativ: Wem fiel das Herz eine Elle tiefer herab? Dem Schneider

Zu 3:  Aus meiner Erfahrung ist eine solch geschwollene Ausdrucksweise nicht üblich. Ich spreche selbst Hochdeutsch und habe noch nie jemanden so sprechen hören, außer in alten Filmen oder Texten.

Daraus erschließt sich die 4: "Jemandem die Haare kämmen" ist gebräuchlicher als dein anderes Beispiel.