# Aber was bleibt einem anderes übrig?

Tags: sentence-structure

I know that *bleiben übrig* means to be left over, but why is "einem anderes" in Dativ? Is it "Dativ", because it expresses "whose perspective the situation is, .i.e. to whom something is left?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding "ihm" in "so fiel ihm das Herz doch eine Elle tiefer herab"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/understanding-ihm-in-so-fiel-ihm-das-herz-doch-eine-elle-tiefer-herab)

Comment: @Beta No, the question is not a duplicate of the question linked by you. In contrast to the question linked by you, in the question above "übrig bleiben" und "einem übrig bleiben" have different meanings.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet: They don't have different meanings, but one sentence only mentions _that_ something remains, whereas the other additionally mentions _whom_ something remains.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich The **do** have different meanings. In the first one something **remains** in a positive sense, in the second one there is **nothing else left** in a negative sense. Moreother, the second one is an idiom: you cannot change "anderes" by some other word without destroying the original meaning.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet: Ich habe hier noch keinen Kommentar gesehen, der mit positiv/negativ argumentiert hat, und damit richtig gelegen hätte und ich habe viele gesehen. "Es blieb viel Kuchen übrig" kann positiv gedeutet werden, als man morgen noch davon hat, als auch negativ, weil es den Gästen nicht geschmeckt hat. Ein Vielfraß kann am Kaffeetisch als letzter bedient werden, nachdem sich die anderen alle die kleinen Stücke haben reichen lassen, und glücklich feststellen, dass er das größte nehmen muss - es bleibt ihm nichts anderes übrig.

Comment: @userunknown In der Tat, "anderes" ist durch "sonst" austauschbar. Insofern handelt es sich - entgegen meiner obigen Behauptung - nicht um ein Idiom. Dennoch ist die Bedeutung nicht exakt dieselbe, sondern übertragene, was auch die Duden-Reaktion nicht anders sieht: ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend korrigiert. Was jedoch Deinen vorhergehenden Kommentar angeht: ich kann mit dem nichts anfangen; weder spielt die Anzahl der von Dir gesehenen Kommentare eine Rolle noch kann ich Deine Beispiele auf meinen Kommentar in irgendeiner Weise übertragen. Du kannst ja Deine eigene Antwort schreiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Aber was bleibt einem anderes übrig?" "einem anderes" is not one part of the sentence, but two different ones:

1. "einem" = "ihm/ihr/jemandem" (Dativ of "man")
2. "anderes" (attribute/qualifier of "was")

Those are two different expressions:

"übrig bleiben" = "to be left [over]"
"für jemanden/einen übrig bleiben" = "to be left [over] for somebody"

In contrast to that:

"Ihm/Einem bleibt nichts anderes übrig." = "He/You won't have any choice" / "He/You won't have any other alternatives."

The latter one is the figurative meaning of ["übrig bleiben"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/uebrig_bleiben).

---

You could reformulate "Aber was bleibt einem anderes übrig?" as

> Aber **was anderes** bleibt einem übrig?

The word order here is not very common but the sentence is still grammatically correct. Here it is more obvious that "anderes" is an attribute/qualifier of "was".

Comment: "Einem" is the dative counterpart of "man". https://deutschegrammatik20.de/pronomen/indefinitpronomen/indefinitpronomen-man-einer/

Comment: @RHa Thx, I included into the answer.