# Why does one say in German, "Ihm schlug das Herz bis zum Hals"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Ihm schlug das Herz bis zum Hals.

What is the grammatical function of "ihm" in this context? I know that literally "ihm" here means for him.

Comment: You might be interested in learning that German hearts can do also other things using dative: *Das Herz sank ihm in die Hose. Das Herz hüpfte ihm im Leibe.*

Comment: siehe auch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/understanding-ihm-in-so-fiel-ihm-das-herz-doch-eine-elle-tiefer-herab?rq=1

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann and in all the person is dative :-)

Comment: @Iris thanks very useful ... did n't find that before

Comment: In this case, "ihm" means something like "to him". I.e. it happened to him, that his heart "pounded up to his throat", i.e. very heavily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This construct is a dative form which is also present in Latin, and not directly translatable into languages like English where the dative has almost vanished.

In languages that still have a living dative, this case can express

- *ownership* - **My** heart is beating to the neck - **Mir** schlägt das Herz bis zum Hals
- *beneficiary* or *aggrieved party* - **Mir** wurde das Auto gestohlen (The car was stolen **from me**)

Those are the two most important usages of dative (apart from receivership of something, which is the same as in English), beyond that there are some more you might want to look up in a German grammar, like *dativus ethicus*, *iudicantis* and *finalis*, .

Answer (score 5):

> Das Herz (Subjekt) schlug ihm (Objekt) bis zum Hals.

So the grammatical function is simply "Objekt". The meaning would translate to something like

> His heart was beating that hard so that he can feel it in his throat.

Comment: His heart is beating ... Sein Herz schlug .... ?

Comment: Sorry, of course it is past tense.

Comment: The point is, that in the German sentence there is no statement about who is the owner of the heart. It is not »sein Herz«. It is »das Herz«. So in the English translation it should not be »his heart«. It must be »the heard«. Then it is clear, that the German *»ihm«* turns to *»so that **he** can feel«*, whereas there is not a single word about feeling in the German sentence.

Comment: I was only talking about the meaning, not the literal translation, because the question was only about the grammatical function of *ihm*. Nevertheless you are right. I did not think about this form hardly existing in English, although a construction like "it is pleasing to me" comes close.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I guess it is debatable which form of the dative this really is. There are several possible translations of **mir** here: *my heart* - dativus possesivus, *I felt my heart beating* - dativus iudicantis, *I suffered from my heart beating* - dativus incommodi. The real thing is probably a mix of all.

Comment: @tofro  Looking at a number of similar phrases (*Das Herz rutschte ihm in die Hose. Das Herz hüpfte ihm im Leibe*) I feel inclinde to interpret this as simply *dativus locativus* (indicating a place), i.e. "Where did it do this? In him!" See also *Dem Fenster ist die Scheibe rausgefallen*, *Der Fichte ist die Spitze abgebrochen*. (Although, okay, especially in the latter two you may well see *dativus incommodi* too.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: »Die Lisa hat **mir** das Auto kaputt gemacht.« Wo siehst du da einen Ort?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. Da sehe ich natürlich auch keinen Ort. Ich habe aber ja auch nicht behauptet, dass Dativ immer Lokativ ist; und du hast ein ganz anderes Beispiel genommen. Beim Verb *kaputtmachen* könnte man wohl von einer anderen Unterart des Dativs ausgehen als bei ven Verben *abbrechen* oder *rausfallen*. Wenn man mal die These ausprobieren möchte, dass die Dativart mit dem Verb recht fest verbunden ist.

Comment: Aber alle Beispiele haben gemeinsam, dass damit ein Nutznießer oder Opfer (allgemeiner: Empfänger) der Handlung gemeint ist, und genau das ist die Aussage meiner Antwort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Ja, es ist sicherlich ein fruchtbarer Ansatz, beim Dativ vor allem ein Opfer/Nutznießer-Verhältnis zu sehen. Funktioniert ja auch bei der Fichte und dem Fenster. Funktioniert jedoch nicht recht beim Herz das *ihm* zur Brust schlägt. Den Protagonisten hier als Opfer oder Nutznießer zu sehen, erfordert zu viel geistige Gymnastik. Eher ist es hier doch ein Lokativ. Und wenn man eine Lokativfunktion schon mal zulässt für den Dativ, dann kann man sie auch bei Fichte und Fenster sehen. (Das soll nicht heißen, du hast unrecht. Es bieten sich einfach mehrere Interpretationen an.)

Answer (score 4):

You often find personal pronouns in dative case in German sentences, that are hard to translate into English, because there is a grammatical feature in German, that doesn't exist in English. Here are some other examples:

> Das Buch gefällt **mir.**
>   The book likes **me**? What?
>   I like this book. (Ich mag dieses Buch.)
>
> Der Hut flog **ihm** vom Kopfe.
>   The hat flew **him**? from the head?
>   The wind blew the hat from his head. (Der Wind blies den Hut von seinem Kopf.)
>
> Das Herz schlug **ihm** bis zum Hals.
>   The heard beat **him** to the neck???
>   His heart was thumping. (Sein Herz pochte.)

This personal pronoun in dative case marks the receiver (beneficiary, victim) of the action.

The book is the subject, it does something. It pleases/suits. (There is no one-to-one translation of *gefallen* in English, that can be used the same way.) The dative object tells us, who is the person, that receives what the book is emitting.

In the second example the pronoun doesn't mark the owner of the hat. The man could also have worn a strangers hat. But the man was the victim of whatever made the hat to fly away (it was probably the wind).

In the last example, it is obviously his heart that was beating, but this is not what this pronouns says. The sentence does not say "**his** heart is beating". Is literally says

> **A** heart is beating, and **he** can feel this heartbeat in his neck.

So, here again the pronoun doesn't talk about ownership. It tells us who is the *victim* (i.e. the person that recognizes the heartbeat)

Also the sentence from your other question:

> Ihm blieb vor Schreck der Atem weg.

The pronoun *ihm* tells us who was suffering from being breathless. (Who was the victim of this action?)

Comment: In the first example, "gefallen" should not be translated by "like", but by "please", and then the verbatim translation "the book pleases me" is in fact possible. "To like" means "mögen", not "gefallen".

Comment: Another example: "Ihm steht das Wasser bis zum Hals".

Comment: @Uwe: Erklär das mal Facebook (like → gefällt mir)

Comment: Endlich Whataboutism auf german.SE

Answer (score 1):

The whole phrase means, "For him, the heart was beating into the throat.

In English, we would say, "*His* heart was beating into the throat."

But German doesn't use this construction for this, and similar, phrases. So they would use "ihm" where we would use "his"

Comment: I would rather use "throat" than "neck". That is where you feel it, when the heart is pounding (for excitement, or fear).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Changed per your suggestion. Thanks for your help